# Assistance assigning a List to update to a variable via a Button in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I've been making a program for class that uses a Caesar cipher to encode and decode text, and I've been trying to get it working with Tkinter, which I'm a complete noob at.

I was trying to get the decode to brute force my cipher-text to show all the possibilities (one obviously being the original plaintext).

So I  wanted to make a list on the window that when I press the decode button takes the input and lists all 25 possibilities. Whenever I try this however it only will list out the strings rather than any variables. Hopefully any of this makes sense.

Here's my code:

```
import string
import collections
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Encoder")
root.geometry("500x400")

code = StringVar()
code.set('')
decode = StringVar()
decode.set('')

def caesar(rotate_string, number_to_rotate_by):
    upper = collections.deque(string.ascii_uppercase)
    lower = collections.deque(string.ascii_lowercase)

    upper.rotate(number_to_rotate_by)
    lower.rotate(number_to_rotate_by)

    upper = ''.join(list(upper))    
    lower = ''.join(list(lower))

    return rotate_string.translate(str.maketrans(string.ascii_uppercase, upper)).translate(str.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, lower))


def callback():
    global code
    our_string = e.get()
    random_number = random.randint(1, 25)
    code.set(caesar(our_string, random_number))

def press():
    global decode
    our_string = e.get() 
    random_number = random.randint(1, 25)
    for i in range(len(string.ascii_uppercase)):
        list1.insert(i, "|", caesar(our_string, i))


var = StringVar()

e = Entry(root, textvariable=var)
e.pack()
b = Button(root, text="ENCODE", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()
b2 = Button(root, text="DECODE", width=10, command=press)
b2.pack()

l = Label(root, textvariable=code, anchor=NW, justify=LEFT, wraplength=398)
l.pack()
l.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor=CENTER)
list1 = Listbox(root)
list1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=CENTER)
list1.insert(END)
list1.update_idletasks()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The first argument for `insert` is the insertion point. If you don't want to calculate where that is, you can use 'end' instead. Also, the `print` function is the only function that will automatically convert and concatenate multiple inputs. All other functions you need to use string formatting to make the string.

```
for i in range(len(string.ascii_uppercase)):
    # make the output string
    result = '{:0>2}|{}'.format(i, caesar(our_string, i))

    # add this string to the listbox
    list1.insert(END, result)
```